# About Newton's law of cooling differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An egg with temperature $20°C$ is put in a pan of water that is  heating up. The temperature of water in $°C$  is described by the function $f (t) = 100 -50e ^ {-0.2t}$
where $t$ is the time in minutes from the moment egg is being placed in water.
The temperature rise rate of the egg is proportional to the difference between the water and the egg's own temperature where the proportionality ratio is $0.8$. When is the temperature of the egg $90°C?$

Comment: Hey user514750, in the future you can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts

Comment: What are your thoughts about the problem?  What did you get stuck on?

Comment: Is this a homework or practice exam problem? It does not look like a natural math question from any other context.

Comment: Yes, it is a exam problem, I tried everything but could not solve it.

Answer (score 2):

**Take into account that if you exclude the differential equation, this is not a mathematics questions (mostly physics). Also always show your effort/attempt while asking a question, except if you're completely clueless. Below is a hint/explanation to help and lead you to the solution :**

Newton's Law of Cooling states that the rate of change of the temperature of an object is proportional to the difference between its own temperature and the ambient temperature (i.e. the temperature of its surroundings).

Accordingly, rate of change in temperature $T$, $\frac{dT}{dt}$ would be proportional to $T-T_a$ where $T_a$ is the ambient temperature.

Taking into account the proportionality ratio which is $0.8$, the differential equation in this case is :

$$\frac{dT}{dt} = -0.8(T-T_a)$$

But on our case, $T_a = f(t)$, so the differential equation becomes :

$$\frac{dT}{dt} = 0.8(T-f(t)) \Rightarrow \frac{dT}{dt} = -0.8(T + 50e^{-0.2t} - 100) \Leftrightarrow \frac{dT}{dt}=-0.8T - 40e^{-0.2t} + 80$$

Can you now solve this differential equation and yield your results ?

Comment: There's a sign error in the differential equation. $T - T_a$ should be $T_a - T$.

Comment: @SebastianConybeare The object is not cooling, it's heating up.

Comment: Yes. It's heating up because it is cooler than its environment. Thus $T - T_a$ is negative. As the equation is currently written, $T - T_a$ being negative would imply that the object is cooling.

Comment: @SebastianConybeare You're correct, it's too late !